# CSS: Why doesn't the photo scale?

Tags: javascript, css, height, gallery

I have created an image viewer, and for some reason the image doesn't scale to the page (I am using: `height: 82%, width: auto`). You can see the problem on my website, [guyzyl.org](http://guyzyl.org). Go to a gallery and enter a photo to view the problem.    Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/height => "If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly, the value computes to auto." and `DIV#viewer` does not have explicitly specified height...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting it to

```
#viewer img {
    max-height: 82%;
    max-width: 100%;
    }
```

This should achieve the result you want.

Comment: max-height and max-width wont scale dimensions. it just sets a limit for the actual scale.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:block`  for CSS of `img` .

Also, the parent container should have specified dimensions when you are using `auto` for width and height of children.